# Database/ Table not getting created

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sqlite

SQLite database or table aren't being created.

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "employee_directory1";

    protected Context context;
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String s;
        try {
            Toast.makeText(context, "1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sql);
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(in, null);
            NodeList statements = doc.getElementsByTagName("statement");
            for (int i=0; i<statements.getLength(); i++) {
                s = statements.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                db.execSQL(s);
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(context, t.toString(), 50000).show();
        }
    }
```

**sql.xml file**

```
<sql>
<statement>
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    firstNAme VARCHAR(500), 
    lastNAme VARCHAR(500))

</statement>
```

**Another File on create**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        searchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchText);
        db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Remove the `try-catch`, uninstall your app to remove the old database file and see if there's an exception.

Comment: done all those things.

Comment: firstName column does not exists error is coming.

Answer (score 0):

**in your code sql query execute in parts**
please change code in `oncreate`  of  `DatabaseHelper` . I was successfully created table

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String s = null;
        try {
            Toast.makeText(context, "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sql);
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                    .newDocumentBuilder();
            org.w3c.dom.Document doc = builder.parse(in, null);
            NodeList statements = doc.getElementsByTagName("statement");
            for (int i = 0; i < statements.getLength(); i++) {
                s = s.concat( statements.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());

            }
            Log.d("SQLEXAMPLE", s);
            db.execSQL(s);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(context, t.toString(), 50000).show();
        }
    }
```